# C# - DataGridView not displaying full query result

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I'm working on a project and I add a query on navicat that displayed the results I wanted perfectly but when I used that same query on my project it only showed 5 rows of results.

the code im using for filling the datagridview and fetching the data is the following.

```
    string cs = "*info*";
    MySqlConnection liga = new MySqlConnection(cs);
    string query = "*I have the full query futher down, its big and it looks stange in here*";
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(query, liga);
    int nInt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ni", nInt);
    try
    {
        liga.Open();
        MySqlDataReader leitor = comando.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        tabela.Load(leitor);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;
        leitor.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        liga.Close();
    }
```

QUERY

```
SELECT
disciplinas.nome AS Disciplina,
mods_alunos.numero,
mods_alunos.nota

FROM
mods_alunos

INNER JOIN disciplinas ON mods_alunos.codDisc = disciplinas.codDisc

WHERE
nInterno = @ni
```

I've come to the conclusion that it has to do with the INNER JOIN because is i just do SELECT * FROM mods_alunos it displays more than 5 results

EDIT 1:[image: table schema]

[image: What i should be getting on DGV]

Comment: There is no way for us to know what result is correct, we don't have your data or your requirements. But it may be that you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want all rows from `mods_alunos` and nulls for the other table where there is no match.

Comment: i've tried with the left outer join it didnt change the results. Gave me the same in navicat and project

Comment: That's what I mean by we cannot know for sure, and why I did not post it as answer. As Rahul suggests, we would need to know what your data looks like and what result you expect to get. There is nothing wrong with the query just by looking at it.

Comment: just edited the post with some pictures

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT
disciplinas.nome AS Disciplina,
mods_alunos.numero,
mods_alunos.nota    
FROM mods_alunos    
LEFT OUTER JOIN disciplinas ON mods_alunos.codDisc = disciplinas.codDisc    
WHERE nInterno = @ni
```

Comment: Your query and mine give the same results in navicat and on the application

Comment: @Cacheira, then post your table schema along with sample data

Answer (score -1):

You have used ExecuteReader method which returns only 1 row at a time.
You can use ExecuteScalar method which returns a complete table which can be used to fill Gridview.

Comment: The `Load()` method on `DataTable` takes a reader, the code is correct. And `ExecuteScalar` does not return a complete table.